# PostgreSQL Function with case statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm new to functions in SQL and I'm currently working with PostgreSQL. I have two tables that I'm mainly working with and the tables have around 4-5 million rows each. One, we'll call it the transaction table, table has one to many different transactions for an ID, the ID could have been added, deleted or updated in a master table. The other table, called registration table, has one record for each ID that has the name, address, dob, etc. I need to go through the transaction table and depending on the "reason code" either insert that record into the registration table, update the record of that ID in the registration table, or delete the record out of the registration table.

My plan was to first move all the record for the lowest ID into a "current working transaction" table, and then use a case statement to look at the value of the "transaction type" field and perform either an insert, delete, or update. This would continue until all the records were gone from the working transaction table. Each time an ID was finished with the case statement and gone through all the transactions, then they would be removed from current working transactions, leaving only the current ID being worked in the transaction table.

I've been working on this function, and don't get any errors when creating the function, but when I execute it, the only thing that happens is the records get moved into the current transaction table. The case statement doesn't seem to be going through.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION makeUpdates() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    code VARCHAR := (SELECT reasoncode FROM current_working_trans);
BEGIN
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO current_working_trans 
            SELECT * FROM test_working_trans 
            WHERE identification_number = (SELECT MIN(identification_number) FROM test_working_trans);
        DELETE FROM test_working_trans
            WHERE identification_number = (SELECT MIN(identification_number) FROM test_working_trans);

        CASE
            WHEN code IN('NEW','REACTIVATE','TRANSFER IN','REINSTATE','CHANGE IN') THEN
                    INSERT INTO registration_table
                        (sourceid, lastname, firstname, middlename, namesuffix, reghousenum, reghousesfx, regstname, regsttype, 
                         regstpost, regunitnumber, regcity, regsta, regzip5, registrationaddr1, registrationaddr2, county_fips, 
                         jurisname, precinct, precinctname, cd_nextelection, sd_next_election, ld_nextelection, sex, birthyear, 
                         birthmonth, birthday, registrationdate, mailingaddr1, mailingaddr2, mailcity, mailsta, mailzip5)
                    SELECT identification_number, last_name, first_name, middle_name, suffix, house_number, housenumbersuffix, 
                    street_name, streettypecodename, post_direction, apt_num, city, state, zip::int, address_line_1, address_line_2, 
                    locality_code::int, localityname, precinct_code_value, precinctname, cong_code_value::int, stsenate_code_value::int, 
                    sthouse_code_value::int, gender, EXTRACT(year FROM dob), EXTRACT(month FROM dob), EXTRACT(day FROM dob), 
                    registration_date, mailing_address_line_1, mailing_address_line_2, mailing_city, mailing_state, LEFT(mailing_zip, 5)    
                    FROM current_working_trans;
                    --ADD ON CONFLICT STATEMENT FOR IF IT'S ALREADY DONE
                    DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE reasoncode = code;
            WHEN code IN('INACTIVE','ACTIVE CANCEL','DECLARED NON-CITIZEN','INELIGIBLE','OUT OF STATE','MENTALLY INCAPACITATED',
                  'INACTIVE CANCEL - PURGE','CHANGE OUT','FELON','REGISTRAR ERROR','TRANSFER OUT','DECEASED','INACTIVE CANCEL - OTHER',
                  'PER CHOICE') THEN
                    INSERT INTO deletions
                    SELECT * FROM registration_table
                    WHERE registration_table.sourceid = current_working_trans.identification_number;
                    DELETE FROM registration_table WHERE registration_table.sourceid = current_working_trans.identification_number;
                    DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE reasoncode = code;
            WHEN code = 'NAME CHANGE' THEN 
                    UPDATE registration_table
                    SET firstname = current_working_trans.first_name,
                        lastname = current_working_trans.last_name,
                        middlename = current_working_trans.middle_name,
                        namesuffix = current_working_trans.suffix
                    FROM current_working_trans
                    WHERE sourceid = identification_number; 
                    DELETE FROM current_working_trans WHERE reasoncode = code; 
            ELSE 
                INSERT INTO deletions (firstname, lastname) SELECT first_name, last_name FROM current_working_trans;
        END CASE;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    END LOOP; 
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Do you not get anything in the deletions table? How many records are in the `current_working_trans` table when you set `code`?

Comment: use if/else logic - case is used to determine a value not an action

Comment: @JNevill, I just got records in the 'deletions' table when I removed the declaration of 'code' and switched it to a query result but if there is an ID that has multiple records in the 'current_working_trans' table  then I get an error 'ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are doing here, but perhaps separate the declaration of `code` and the setting of code. Set it after the INSERT with `SELECT reasoncode INTO code FROM current_working_trans;` just before the CASE. Again.. I'm making some assumption of your logic flow.

Comment: @DanielMarcus: In Postges it's a control structure too. See "42.6.2.4. Simple `CASE`" and "42.6.2.5. Searched `CASE`" ([42.6.2. Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS))